# Bootstrap center div stays in long rectangle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

I have already created this basic web page that has a header with an image and words, then below that header I have 3 blocks of text, I have one last thing to add which is another block of text below the 3 others. This block needs to be centered and extend downward instead of sideways when the text is long.

See layout example.
[image]

[Here is a live example with lots of text.](http://ssiclouddev.azurewebsites.net/pages/EmailFromCampaign?From=Test%20Name&FromEmail=test@test.com&FromSubject=Contacting%20about%20a%20product&Content=BlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblahBlahblah)

Here is my current code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-left">
            <p>Having trouble viewing this email? <a href="<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>">View in browser</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid page-header">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="http://ssiclouddev.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Icons/favicon-96x96.png" />
                <h1>Susquehanna Software Inc.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <h3>From:  <% =Request.QueryString["From"] %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <h3>Email: <% =Request.QueryString["FromEmail"] %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <h3>Subject: <% =Request.QueryString["FromSubject"] %></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3><% =Request.QueryString["Content"] %></h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h3><% =Request.QueryString["Content"] %></h3>
      </div>
 </div>
```

With

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">  
        <h3><% =Request.QueryString["Content"] %></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I told you this exact answer initially and you told me it was incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your example actually is working fine. But because your content is just one massive word it continues outside of the parent. To check this, add this CSS: `word-wrap:break-word` to your `h3`.

[image]

I suggest using a source of dummy text such as [Ipsum Lorem](http://www.lipsum.com/feed/html) or [Bacon Ipsum](http://baconipsum.com/) in future

Comment: That makes it appear off the left side 3 space yeah, but the text still extends sideways so that scrolling to the right has to happen.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly with what is now correct

Comment: Danny you answered my question but I used the formatted code above as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML (you shouldn't nest `col-` classes in another `col-` class without new `row`):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <h3><% =Request.QueryString["Content"] %></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line):

```
h3 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```